# Get the id of the slickgrid from its instance

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I'd like to get the id of a slickgrid instance using the instance variable (any value representing the unique instance would be fine).

The best I have found is parsing the uid out o the dom element:

```
var sg = new Slick.Grid(...)
var classes = pg.mainGrid.getCanvasNode().parentNode.parentNode.classList
for (var i=i, len=classes.length; i<len; i++) {
  if (classes[i].contains('slickgrid')){
    var id = classes[i]
    break;
  }
}
```

This is clearly silly. Anyone found a better way?

Comment: Why the downvote? This is specific and practical. Contains a code sample. I don't get it.

Comment: Upvoted, this question seems fine, and the downvoter didn't leave a comment.

Comment: What are you planning to do with the uid? The author intentionally leaves out these types of things from the public interface to prevent people from "shooting themselves in the foot" as it were.

Comment: @idbehold, if Leibman actually said it was out on purpose, then I would ask why. I suspect this is speculation though. You can have 2 slickgrids on one page, so, shouldn't I be able to identify them separately? Log messages from them so I can tell which is which? Bind a single handler to the events of both grids? There are any number of legitimate uses cases for this I think. Mine is about pinning columns.

Comment: Simply use `grid.getContainerNode().id` its already defined.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best answer may be to add the method to SlickGrid. Here's the commit:

https://github.com/SimpleAsCouldBe/SlickGrid/commit/bc1342c25a81a7adbe6d52a9ece79ad716307a07

```
    +    // A simple way to expose the uid to consumers, who might care which slickgrid instance they're dealing with.
    +    function getId() {
    +      return uid;
    +    }
    ...
    +    "getId": getId,
```